# How to filter a date range?

Tags: 8, views, datetime

I'm having troubles figuring out how to filter by date using the date range module from Drupal 8 core.

I, of course, found this post: [How to filter a View by Date Range (start, end)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/226884)

But this doesn't tell me how to use the filter, it only makes the filter work better. So I used this patch but how to make this filter work?

I'm creating a calendar with cultural events and I want to be able to filter on date and genre with exposed filters. So let's say I have a design event from 05-01-2018 until 05-02-2018 (`dd-mm-yyyy`).

And I want it to show up when I'm searching for what is going on today or this month that concerns design? How to set up the filter for this?

What is the best and most simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this I have two exposed filters for my `begin_date` (`begin_filter_1` and `begin_filter_2`) and two exposed filters for my `end_date` (`end_filter_1` and `end_filter_2`).

- When the `begin_filter_1` is entered, this input will be copied to `end_filter_2`.
- When the `end_filter_1` is entered, this input will be copied to `begin_filter_2`.

No the filter looks like this

```
Published Yes

AND

Category - Exposed (Taxonomy Term) = Design
Begin Filter 1 - Exposed >= Begin_Date
End Filter 1 - Exposed <= End_Date

AND

Has Taxonomy Term - Exposed = Design
Begin Filter 2 - Exposed(but hidden via css) <= Begin_Date
End Filter 2 - Exposed(but hidden via css) >= End_Date
```

As you can see in the second Group I use a different filter to filter on the category. This is because of a bug in Drupal Core: 
[Complex Filter Criteria no Results](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252604/complex-filter-criteria-no-results)